# How to check whether the Redis server is running

Tags: php, fuelphp

How to check whether the Redis server is running?

If it's not running, I want to fallback to using the database.

I'm using the FuelPHP framework, so I'm open to a solution based on this, or just standard PHP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you can do is try to get an instance (\Redis::instance()) and work with it like this:

```
try
{
    $redis = \Redis::instance();
    // Do something with Redis.
}
catch(\RedisException $e)
{
    // Fall back to other db usage.
}
```

But preferably you'd know whether redis is running or not. This is just the way to detect it on the fly.

Answer (score 266):

You can use command line to determine if redis is running:

```
redis-cli ping
```

you should get back

```
PONG
```

that indicates redis is up and running.

Comment: it won't work on redis cluster

Comment: In any case, that response is based on this official `redis` reference [redis-cli](https://redis.io/docs/ui/cli/)

Answer (score 18):

```
redis-cli -h host_url -p 6379 ping
```

Answer (score 11):

All answers are great,

aAnother way can be to check `if default REDIS port is listening`

i.e port number  6379
`lsof -i:6379`

if you don't get any output for above command then it implies redis is not running.

Comment: This is the way if you are running it off a docker container

Answer (score 7):

You can use this command on linux:

```
systemctl status redis-server
```

It will give you this output:

```
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-01-11 19:14:30 UTC; 1 day 4h ago
Docs: http://redis.io/documentation, man:redis-server(1)
Main PID: 43270 (redis-server)
Status: "Ready to accept connections"
Tasks: 5 (limit: 477)
Memory: 18.5M
CPU: 3min 34.450s
CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
└─43270 "/usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
Jan 11 19:14:30 ip-172-31-17-230 systemd[1]: Starting Advanced key-value store...
Jan 11 19:14:30 ip-172-31-17-230 systemd[1]: Started Advanced key-value store.
```

Answer (score 5):

you can do it by this way.

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

echo $redis->ping();
```

and then check if it print `+PONG`, which show redis-server is running.

Answer (score -2):

systemctl status redis

will help you

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers

Comment: `redis` instead of `redis-server` as used in the other answer? Why?