# How to get the redis db that is set?

Tags: redis

Hi is there a way to know the active db on redis? 
As for now i am using `$this->redis->select(7)`, so I basically select it manually. But is there a way where i can get the redis db that is set?

Comment: Answere here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866541/how-to-check-whether-the-redis-server-is-running

Comment: On the CLI, you can also try: $ redis-server

Answer (score 1):

While there is no command to know which database the current connection is using, however, you can use **CLIENT LIST** which lists the current db in use for each client.

Ex:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> client list
id=6 addr=127.0.0.1:64502 fd=8 name= age=7 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=client
```

You can also use **CLIENT SETNAME** to set name of the client during connection and filter the **CLIENT LIST** output to that name.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> client setname hello
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> client list
id=6 addr=127.0.0.1:64502 fd=8 name=hello age=189 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=client
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

for more details see the redis document https://redis.io/commands/client-list